# Hover event change after click

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a title div that when clicked, opens a description div. When the title is hovered, and the description is closed, another div 'read more' appears. When the title is hovered, and the description is already open, 'read less' appears instead. If a different title is clicked while another description is open, the previous description closes and the current one opens.
My problem is that I cannot get the hover event to change after the click event.

I have a JSFiddle with both codes but have been failing to combine them.

https://jsfiddle.net/qkp91vgw/8/

```
    $(".tooltitle").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $div = $(this).nextAll('.tooldescription');
      var $arrow = $(this).find(".arrow");
        $(".tooldescription").not($div).slideUp('slow');
        $(".arrow").not($arrow).css({'background-image':'url("../media/arrowdown.gif")'});
        if ($div.is(":visible")) {
            $div.slideUp('slow')
            $(this).find(".arrow").css({'background-image':'url("../media/arrowdown.gif")'});
        }  else {
           $div.slideDown('slow');
           $(this).find(".arrow").css({'background-image':'url("../media/arrowup.gif")'});
        }
    });
});
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tooltitle").hover(function() {
        if ($(this).nextAll('.tooldescription').is(":visible")) {
    $(".toolreadless").css({
            'left': $(this).offset().left,
            'top': $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 5,
    }).stop(true,true).fadeIn(1000);
        }  else {
    $(".toolreadmore").css({
            'left': $(this).offset().left,
            'top': $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 5,
    }).stop(true,true).fadeIn(1000);
        }
   },
    function(){
    $(".toolreadmore").css({
            'left': $(this).offset().left,
            'top': $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 5,
    }).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
        $(".toolreadless").css({
            'left': $(this).offset().left,
            'top': $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 5,
    }).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
  }
    );
});
```

With the code separated, read less appears if the mouse leaves the title and re-enters, as expected. I am failing to combine them so the click event changes the hover text/div at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hover over `.tooltitle` the code executes once, showing the the proper read more/less message accordingly. However, when you click on `.tootltitle` that message needs to change. The function responsible for changing the message does not execute on click events.

The simple solution is to add your CSS attributes aswell as `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` methods to the click event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tooltitle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $div = $(this).nextAll('.tooldescription');
    var $arrow = $(this).find(".arrow");
    $(".tooldescription").not($div).slideUp('slow');
    $(".arrow").not($arrow).css({
      'background-image': 'url("../media/arrowdown.gif")'
    });
    if ($div.is(":visible")) {
      $div.slideUp('slow')
      $(this).find(".arrow").css({
        'background-image': 'url("../media/arrowdown.gif")'
      });
    } else {

      $(".toolreadmore").fadeOut();
      $(".toolreadless").css({
        'left': $(this).offset().left,
        'top': $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 5,
      }).stop(true, true).fadeIn(1000);


      $div.slideDown('slow');
      $(this).find(".arrow").css({
        'background-image': 'url("../media/arrowup.gif")'
      });
    }


  });
});
```

A more complex approach may involve using JQuery `.on`. allowing you to attach multiple event listeners(Specifically hover and click events) to the function responsible for changing the read more/less message. 
You may need to change your event handler aswell.

Something along the lines of:

```
$(".tooltitle").on("mouseover click", function(e)
{

});
```

Comment: Thanks this helped to work out the rest.  Now to position elements properly.